# PHP function call itself to build an array

Tags: php, laravel

Hello I do not know if this is possible, I am trying to build an array but it is not working when using return as it comes back blank but when I do var dump it shows the values...Please here is the code below

```
        public function getURL($category_id,$output=null){

            $getCat = ProductCategory::where("id","=",$category_id)->get();
            if(count($getCat) != 0){
                foreach($getCat as $cat){
                    $parent = $cat->category_id;
                    $output[] = $parent;
                    $this->getURL($parent,$output);
                }
            } else {
                $finish = true;
            }

            if($finish){
                //var_dump($output); this returns what I need
                return $output;
            }

        }
```

Edit
 I am trying to build a list of urls, in my database I have category_id to represent its a sub category. So I am trying to get all the ID's back to build the list of urls

UPDATE

Thanks to @Parziphal he showed me my mistake and fixed it for me. Here is his answer. Thanks everyone for there input too.

```
   public function getURL($categoryId)
   {
     return $this->getParentIdsRecursive($categoryId, []);
   }

   protected function getParentIdsRecursive($categoryId, $ids = [])
   {
     $category = ProductCategory::where("id", $categoryId)->first();

     if ($category && $category->category_id) {
       $ids[] = $category->category_id;
       $ids = $this->getParentIdsRecursive($category->category_id, $ids);
     }

     return $ids;
  }
```

Comment: make a quick change `getURL($category_id,$output=null)` to `getURL($category_id, &$output=null)`

Comment: What's the point of this? Are you by any chance looking for something like `$getCat = ProductCategory::where("id","=",$category_id)->pluck('category_id')` ? [Pluck](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-pluck)

Comment: Did not work :( and I am trying to build a list of urls, in my database I have category_id to represent its a sub category. So I am trying to get all the ID's back to build the list of urls

Comment: OK and `pluck()` does not solve your problem because...?

Comment: Can you provide what the data going into the function looks like and what you expect it to come out like. If I'm honest, I'm having a hard time understanding what you're trying to do.

Comment: I have not used pluck before, sorry I have started reading into pluck it seems that this might be the best way. Thank you! I am relatively new to Laravel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tested this, and I don't understand what you are trying to do, but maybe this works:

```
public function getURL($categoryId)
{
    return $this->getParentIdsRecursive($categoryId, []);
}

protected function getParentIdsRecursive($categoryId, $ids = [])
{
    $category = ProductCategory::where("id", $categoryId)->first();

    if ($category && $category->category_id) {
        $ids[] = $category->category_id;
        $ids = $this->getParentIdsRecursive($category->category_id, $ids);
    }

    return $ids;
}
```

If I'm (and the code is) not wrong, that will return all the category ids up to the first parent.

Comment: Why should the OP try this? Why does this work "maybe"? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: I don't (nobody) understand what he's trying to do, so I can't know if this is what he needs; I'm just trying to make his code work. The method name is "getURL" yet he's getting a bunch of ids. Have you also noticed that he's calling `get` when he's looking records by id? Then he does a foreach when the result will always be one. What I understood is that he's trying to get all the parents ids until there are no parents left, and that's what I did. If this is not what he needs he could explain further...

Comment: @Parziphal omg thank you so much, this has worked perfectly. Sorry for not explaining it properly but this was exactly what I needed! thank you so much and everyone else too for there input

Comment: @JayBlanchard I think I've understood what you tried to mean: you meant that I should explain my code so the OP knows what he did wrong, and that I should explain how to fix the mistake, and how my answer works. Am I right? The thing is that the first question of your comment sounded like you were _disparaging_ my answer. I didn't explain this answer because I wasn't sure the OP wanted this; however if you look at my answers, I usually explain them and comment the code. Thank you for the advice!

Comment: Not meant to be disparaging at all, just trying to help you make your answer better for the OP and others who may view the question and answer when they are trying to solve similar issues.

Comment: Exactly that; you were helping me to improve. When I saw your profile I thought "this sir looks too nice to say what I think he said". It took me a while to realize. Thank you again.